# How to use Java Plugin in Browser with JDK within Mountain Lion OSX?

Tags: macos, java

I do not see any Java Preferences.app in my Utilities directory.

I run a java -version in command line, there was nothing and prompted me to install version 1.6 from apple. It installs successfully.

I do not see any Java related application in my Utilities directory. I open up a web browser (Safari) and see "Missing Plug-in" in place of where any applet should be.

How do I enable the applet from my Java installation?

(On an aside, is it possible to use Java 7 JDK from Oracle such that the browser can recognize it and use it to resolve the "Missing Plugin issue", would prefer Java 7 over Java 6 anyday..)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559) titled,

> "How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 applet plug-in and Web
>   Start functionality"

1. Open Terminal, located in the Utilities folder.
2. Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

   `sudo mkdir -p /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled`
3. Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

   `sudo mv /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled`
4. Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

   `sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`
5. To re-enable Java SE 6 Web Start, enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:

   `sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws`

Comment: This does not appear to apply to Java 7... is it possible with Java 7 JDK too? (i would love to rid myself of 1.6)

Comment: @Charles- Yeah, I'm not sure... The article did begin with this though, `"If, after installing Java for OS X 2012-006 and Java 7, you want to disable Java 7 and re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 plug-in, follow these steps."`  That's why I posted.  I have not actually tried it myself.